# How to compute the following set of ODEs numerically (with ICs)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve the following set of 5 first order ODEs

[image]

Where the variables to consider are $\Theta_0, \Theta_1, \Phi, \delta$ and $v$ and the rest are constants. The initial conditions (ICs) are

[image]

I am running the following MATLAB code, which I include for the curious (following the exact same steps as shown in the solved sample https://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-a-system-of-differential-equations.html)

```
 syms u(t) v(t) w(t) x(t) y(t) a b d G k %Note that u corresponds to the variable v (see #1), v to                
 \delta, w to \Theta_0, x to \Theta_1, y to \Phi and b to \dot a%

 ode1 = diff(w) + diff(y) == -k*x;
 ode2 = diff(x) == (k*w)/3 - (k*y)/3;
 ode3 = diff(v) + 3*diff(y) == i*k*u;
 ode4 = diff(u) == i*k*y - (b*u)/a;
 ode5 = (3*b*(diff(y) + (b*y)/a))/a == 4*G*a^2*d*pi*v - k^2*y + 16*G*a^2*d*pi*w;
 odes = [ode1; ode2; ode3; ode4; ode5]
 [uSol(t), vSol(t), wSol(t), xSol(t), ySol(t)] = dsolve(odes) %Code works, yielding quite "ugly" 
 answers. Next we introduce ICs%

 cond1 = x(0) - i*(u(0))/3 == 0;
 cond2 = v(0) - 3*w(0) == 0;
 cond3 = y(0) - 2*w(0) == 0;
 conds = [cond1; cond2; cond3];
 [uSol(t), vSol(t), wSol(t), xSol(t), ySol(t)] = dsolve(odes,conds) %Code breaks down, giving the 
 output "Invalid initial conditions"%
```

As noted in the comments, the code fails at the very end, indicating that the the initial conditions are invalid.

Why are the provided ICs wrong? How to fix the issue?

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system of ODE seems to be dependent. After transforming Laplace we get

$$
0=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 k \Theta _1(s)+s \Theta _0(s)+s \Phi (s)-\Phi (0) -\Theta _0(0)\\
 -k \Theta _0(s)+\frac{1}{3} k (s \Phi (s)-\Phi (0))+s \Theta _1(s)-\Theta _1(0) \\
 s \delta (s)-\delta (0)+k v(s)+3 (s \Phi (s)-\Phi (0)) \\
 H v(s)-i k \Phi (s)+s v(s)-v(0) \\
 -4 \pi  a^2 G \delta (s) \rho _m-16 \pi  a^2 G \rho  \Theta _0(s)+3 H^2 \Phi (s)+3 H (s \Phi (s)-\Phi (0))+k^2 \Phi (s) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

with characteristic matrix

$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 s & 0 & s & 0 & 0 \\
 -k & 0 & \frac{k s}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 s & s & k \\
 0 & 0 & -i k & 0 & H+s \\
 -16 \pi  a^2 G \rho  & 0 & 3 H^2+3 H s+k^2 & -4 \pi  a^2 G \rho _m & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and $\det(M) = 0$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I am afraid I do not follow the method you employed to solve the set of ODEs. Might you please explain more (or point me to some bibliography so that I can follow) on how you obtained the transformed system and how you constructed the matrix? Besides, did you make use of any software? If yes, did the code I provided work for you?

Comment: When the ODE system is linear with constant coefficients as is your case, the Laplace Transform method can be used. No need for special software because the Laplace transforms are tabulated. Perhaps Matlab has a symbolic processor which calculates those easy transforms. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: Thank you once again, just one last comment. I am struggling to see what functions would satisfy the given set of equations. For instance, what function $\Phi(t)$ would satisfy the given set of ODEs? I do not know how to read it from your solution. It should have a similar form to the one I attached (please see edit).

Comment: The condition $\det(M) = 0$ indicates that at least one of the unknowns depends linearly on the others so the one linearly dependent should have initial conditions  also dependent. So we have only four independent  initial conditions to the five unknowns. Regarding your edit, what is the meaning for $f(x)$ ?

Comment: From a linear homogeneous ODE system with constant coefficients, the solution involves functions as polynomials, $e^{\alpha t}, \sin(\alpha t),\cos(\alpha t),\sinh(\alpha t),\cosh(\alpha t)$, constant and products between them so your $f(x)$ is not included in this class of functions.

Comment: Cesareo, I'll study the Laplace Transform method and then come back

Comment: Great! We will continue later.

Comment: I understand your point now, thanks